# How to make pages/word documents open in preview first?

Tags: ms-office, preview, pages

As you know word documents open by default in pages, and it takes time to do that. Is there any way I can make those documents open in preview first? (plus any other kind of document that you may know) It would obviously be way faster and less cumbersome.

Comment: It depends whether you mean .doc or .docx. Preview can open .doc [so can be set as default] but it cannot open .docx. Hmm, I just tested, Pages can't open .docx either.

Comment: Pages does open docx files, just tested it to be sure - and had to test as I have done it often before and when I read that it was not possible I could not believe it...

Comment: I did manage to find one that worked & one that didn't. I don't use anything MS often enough to have any kicking around to test.

Answer (score 2):

If you do a right click on this file, but before that you can hold down the Option key  and click “Always open with”.  Then just select Preview.

Comment: And tested this as well. Works and opens fine.

Comment: RE: "but before that you can hold down the Option key " --  The **⌥** _key_ can be pressed and held after the context menu appears as well, it does not necessarily need to be done before. This is because a _right-click_ can be initiated by a _control click_ which would require the **⌥** _key_ to be pressed and held after the context menu appears, not before.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is see the contents of the file, no need to open it at all. Just use Quick Look. Select the file and the hit the spacebar to view the contents.

[Documentation](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/preview-files-with-quick-look-mh14119/mac)

#### View and edit files with Quick Look on Mac

Quick Look offers a fast, full-size preview of nearly any kind of file without opening the file. You can rotate photos, trim audio and video clips, and use Markup—directly in the Quick Look window.

On your Mac, select one or more items, then press the Space bar. A
Quick Look window opens. If you selected multiple items, the first
item is shown.

- *Browse items (if you selected multiple items):* Click the arrows near
  the top-left of the window or press the Left Arrow or Right Arrow
  key. In full screen, click the Play button  to view the items as a
  slideshow.
- *Show items in a grid (if you selected multiple items):* Click the
  Index Sheet button  or press Command-Return.
- *Open an item:* Click Open with [App].
- *Share an item:* Click the Share button , then choose how you want to share the item.

When you’re done, press the Space bar or click the Close button  to close the Quick Look window.